# fill_n vs. for-loop to initialize an array

Tags: c++, optimization, std

I wonder what is the performance difference between `fill_n` and a for-loop when initializing
an array?

Which one is better?

Comment: Did you try testing it yourself? Also, use brace initialization for arrays when possible.

Comment: Why wonder when you can measure?

Comment: Neither `fill_n` nor a `for` loop can be used to _initialize_ an array.

Comment: Sorry about the dumb question, I ask it because I use windows and the time library seem to can be precision to nano-second so I cannot tell the difference.

Comment: @Liang Well that should answer your question then. Even with the most accurate timer available to you, you can't measure the difference. So why the hell should you care about it? It's not going to be measurable anyhow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just tested these three codes (Compiled by GCC 4.7.2 with `-O3` optimization):

I added these two lines to all the codes, because I think without them the GCC optimizer will deceive me.

```
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    arr[i] = arr[i + 1 % SIZE];
```

### 1.cpp

```
#define SIZE (100*1000*1000)
char arr[SIZE];

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        arr[SIZE] = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        arr[i] = arr[i + 1 % SIZE];
}
```

### 2.cpp

```
...
    std::fill_n(arr, SIZE, 0);
...
```

### 3.cpp

```
...
    memset(arr, 0, SIZE);
...
```

Measure times:

```
mostafa@debian:~/Codes/tests/x$ time ./1
real   0m0.073s
user   0m0.008s
sys    0m0.064s

mostafa@debian:~/Codes/tests/x$ time ./2
real   0m0.080s
user   0m0.020s
sys    0m0.056s

mostafa@debian:~/Codes/tests/x$ time ./3
real   0m0.100s
user   0m0.056s
sys    0m0.044s
```

Comment: @jogojapan It's `-O0`, Thanks for your help I will edit my answer.

Comment: Which time am I supposed to be looking at, of the 3?

Answer (score 3):

There's no meaningful performance difference between these approaches. They implement the same thing. And the typical level of complexity of the code is sufficiently low for virtually any modern compiler to realize that both do the same thing and generate essentially the same code.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation according to cppreference.com:

```
template<class OutputIt, class Size, class T>
OutputIt fill_n(OutputIt first, Size count, const T& value)
{
    for (Size i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        *first++ = value;
    }
    return first;
}
```

I believe this answers your question? :P

Comment: This isn't _the_ implementation, but _one possible_ implementation.